# SELECT TABLOCKX then MERGE vs MERGE with TABLOCKX

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, deadlock, sql-server-2017

I would have thought that the following query's would have the same result:

```
MERGE [myTable] AS T WITH (TABLOCKX)
...

SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM [myTable] WITH (TABLOCKX);
MERGE [myTable] AS T
...
```

However, when running my MERGE-statement parellel from multiple processes, the first one will result in deadlocks while the second one runs just fine. Am I missing something here?

I should note that it runs within a transaction.

**Edit**

I have created a sample DDL and testdata to recreate the issue:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[myReference]
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[myTable]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myTable](
    [Primary key] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Dataset key] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Key] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK myTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Primary key] ASC)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myReference](
    [Foreign key] INT NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [FK myReference myTable] FOREIGN KEY ([Foreign key]) REFERENCES [dbo].[myTable] ([Primary key]) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
GO

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [dbo].[usp]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp] @DatasetKey INT AS

WITH Val AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM ( VALUES 
        (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
    ) s ([Value])
)

SELECT t1.[Value]
    + (t2.[Value] - 1) * 10 
    + (t3.[Value] - 1) * 100    
    + (t4.[Value] - 1) * 1000   
    + (t5.[Value] - 1) * 10000  
    + (t6.[Value] - 1) * 100000
    AS [Key]
INTO #t
FROM Val t1
    cross apply Val t2
    cross apply Val t3
    cross apply Val t4
    cross apply Val t5
    cross apply Val t6
;

--SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM [dbo].[myTable] WITH (TABLOCKX);

MERGE [dbo].[myTable] WITH (TABLOCKX) AS T
USING #t AS S
ON T.[Dataset key] = @DatasetKey
    AND T.[Key] = S.[Key]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ([Dataset key], [Key]) VALUES (@DatasetKey, S.[Key])
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND T.[Dataset key] = @DatasetKey THEN
    DELETE
;
GO

EXEC [dbo].[usp] 1
GO

EXEC [dbo].[usp] 2
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[myReference]
SELECT [Primary key]
FROM [dbo].[myTable]
GO
```

When running the following two transactions simultaneously, the result will be a deadlock every single time.

**TRAN 1**

```
BEGIN TRY;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    exec [dbo].[usp] 1;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @XactState INT = XACT_STATE();

    IF @XactState <> 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    THROW;
END CATCH;
```

**TRAN 2**

```
BEGIN TRY;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    exec [dbo].[usp] 2;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @XactState INT = XACT_STATE();

    IF @XactState <> 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    THROW;
END CATCH;
```

**Deadlock report**

```
<deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process273cd96d468" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="process273cd96d468" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 42:1282103608:0 " waittime="2356" ownerId="2255393274" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-11-26T16:11:20.080" XDES="0x296a4fb64d0" lockMode="X" schedulerid="4" kpid="19904" status="suspended" spid="67" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-11-26T16:11:20.080" lastbatchcompleted="2021-11-26T16:11:20.077" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.077" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query" hostname="SV00415" hostpid="21276" loginname="VIECURI\mhoogeveen" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="2255393274" currentdb="42" currentdbname="Test20211126KanDaarnaWeg" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671090784" clientoption2="390200">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="Test20211126KanDaarnaWeg.dbo.usp" line="29" stmtstart="1050" stmtend="1626" sqlhandle="0x03002a00aaa1534ecba70a01ecad000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
MERGE [dbo].[myTable] WITH (TABLOCKX) AS T
USING #t AS S
ON T.[Dataset key] = @DatasetKey
    AND T.[Key] = S.[Key]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ([Dataset key], [Key]) VALUES (@DatasetKey, S.[Key])
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND T.[Dataset key] = @DatasetKey THEN
    DELETE    </frame>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="4" stmtstart="72" stmtend="106" sqlhandle="0x020000009f228824b51645ad1d06b456eabe7b2b24f2e8fe0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
BEGIN TRY;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    exec [dbo].[usp] 2;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @XactState INT = XACT_STATE();

    IF @XactState &lt;&gt; 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    THROW;
END CATCH;   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process273c6c4b088" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 42:1250103494:0 " waittime="2994" ownerId="2255393256" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-11-26T16:11:19.633" XDES="0x27385bfd080" lockMode="X" schedulerid="1" kpid="8752" status="suspended" spid="53" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-11-26T16:11:19.633" lastbatchcompleted="2021-11-26T16:11:19.630" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.630" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query" hostname="SV00415" hostpid="21276" loginname="VIECURI\mhoogeveen" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="2255393256" currentdb="42" currentdbname="Test20211126KanDaarnaWeg" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671090784" clientoption2="390200">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="Test20211126KanDaarnaWeg.dbo.usp" line="29" stmtstart="1050" stmtend="1626" sqlhandle="0x03002a00aaa1534ecba70a01ecad000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
MERGE [dbo].[myTable] WITH (TABLOCKX) AS T
USING #t AS S
ON T.[Dataset key] = @DatasetKey
    AND T.[Key] = S.[Key]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ([Dataset key], [Key]) VALUES (@DatasetKey, S.[Key])
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND T.[Dataset key] = @DatasetKey THEN
    DELETE    </frame>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="4" stmtstart="72" stmtend="106" sqlhandle="0x020000002457720d4bb1099d3682fee9760829cab4bbc2be0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
BEGIN TRY;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    exec [dbo].[usp] 1;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @XactState INT = XACT_STATE();

    IF @XactState &lt;&gt; 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    THROW;
END CATCH;   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="1282103608" subresource="FULL" dbid="42" objectname="Test20211126KanDaarnaWeg.dbo.myReference" id="lock29a7a3f4780" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="1282103608">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process273c6c4b088" mode="IX" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process273cd96d468" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
   </waiter-list>
  </objectlock>
  <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="1250103494" subresource="FULL" dbid="42" objectname="Test20211126KanDaarnaWeg.dbo.myTable" id="lock28a11c39800" mode="X" associatedObjectId="1250103494">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process273cd96d468" mode="X" />
    <owner id="process273cd96d468" mode="X" />
    <owner id="process273cd96d468" mode="X" />
    <owner id="process273cd96d468" mode="X" />
    <owner id="process273cd96d468" mode="X" />
    <owner id="process273cd96d468" mode="X" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process273c6c4b088" mode="X" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </objectlock>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: Hi Menno. Please read this: [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/), specifically the part `SQL Server Merge Concurrency Issues`.

Comment: They should behave the same w.r.t. the locking of `myTable`.  Can you post the deadlock xml?

Comment: `HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK` should sort out most problems in the first version, you probably don't need `TABLOCKX`. See https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/2009/01/31/upsert-race-condition-with-merge/

Comment: @TT Thanks for sharing, didn't know! However, running in a transaction and even with the use of `HOLDLOCK` as suggested by  @Charlieface I can't seem to get it working with the lock hint directly in the MERGE-statement.

Comment: For completeness sake, can you include a tag for the specific SQL Server version as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the difference is that `MERGE with TABLOCKX` initially does take an IX lock, whereas `SELECT ... WITH TABLOCKX` does not.

I verified this profiling the `lock:acquired` event on SQL Server 2019 CU 14, and  with smaller tables was able to repro the deadlock.  It's an extremely short window where this can happen, and the larger tables didn't allow enough concurrency on my system.

This creates a small window where two sessions could acquire IX table locks and neither will be able to escalate to an X lock.

If you want to serialize a block of code, [sp_getapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is the simplest way.

Comment: Add that to the list of problems related to MERGE.